# Fortify Cross-Site Scripting: Poor Validation JSF

Tags: jsf, xss, fortify, secure-coding

Fortify finds Cross-Site Scripting: Poor Validation security issue for two line in my JSF 2.2.1 / primefaces project.

```
<p:treeTable id="tree_dt" value="#{OrganizasyonYetkinlikVeriGirisBean.root}" var="organizasyon">
                            <p:column headerText="Ünite Adı" style="width:350px" filterBy="#{organizasyon.uniteAdi}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                                **<h:outputText value="#{organizasyon.uniteAdi}" escape="true"/>**
                            </p:column>

<p:treeTable id="tree_dt" value="#{OrganizasyonYetkinlikVeriGirisBean.root}" var="organizasyon">
                                <p:column headerText="Ünite Adı" style="width:25%" filterBy="#{organizasyon.uniteAdi}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                                    **<h:inputTextarea value="#{organizasyon.uniteAdi}" readonly="true" rows="2" escape="true"/>**
                                </p:column>
```

I have added implicitly escape="true" but, problem still continue.

Answer (score 0):

Neither the treeTable, column nor the inputTextArea have *escape* in their [list of attributes](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_2.pdf).

Your scanner might not be pointing on the right line of markup but can be looking on the right page. Look for other objects along with those treeTable that have the escape attribute available and set it to true.

Comment: I know all elements have implicitly escape=true property in JSF.